# Should I edit the question title to improve it?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

The question *[Matrix manipulation (rotation/rolling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985765/matrix-manipulation-rotation-rolling)* would be better named "Matrix Rotation in Java" or perhaps just "Matrix rotation".

Are we encouraged/discouraged to make such an edit?

Has there been a debate already about using "Java" in the title as well as in the tag?

Comment: Is "rotation" in fact the correct technical term for that particular transformation?  Personally when I hear the term "matrix rotation" I'm thinking of different types of operations than this, but then again it's not a field I've spent a ton of time in.

Comment: Either way, it's Java, not JAVA.

Comment: I won't advise on the specific case, but in general: yes, if you can improve the title, edit it.

Comment: Title are frequently wrong here, or ask a different question from what is really being asked in the body of the question. By all means fix them.

Answer (score 15):

Titles are one of the most important and most forgotten things when doing edits.

**By all means, if you can fix a title to match the question do so.**  And while you are there, fix the other things too (tags and body)... but don't forget to fix the title.  If everything else is good in the body, fixing the title alone is a good improvement too.

All too often people answer the title without reading the question.  The title is what people see first when looking at a question, its part of the indexing on Google.  These are key reasons to fix it.

As to 'JAVA' (should be "Java" but that's a minor nit) - tags are not useful in titles ("Java: how to do matrixes"), but organically worded questions ("How to do matrix rotation in Java") are much more natural to read, search, and find.

Comment: Sometimes its the title that's right and the body that's wrong or vice versa and you don't really know until an answer is chosen.

Comment: I frequently answer the title myself, regardless of what it says in the question. If that's not what the OP was asking, that's his problem, not mine.

Comment: @EJP but that is *exactly* why people should edit the title to match the body of the question. If, after some work on clarifying the question one should also remember to update the title along with the body. Having answers to the wrong question isn't necessarily *your* problem, but it makes the question less useful for the person getting there from google and makes the site seem more like a forum (with tangental posts) than a Q&A site (with the answer to the question).