# Should old titles be updated to be more general?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I realize this question is similar to [Should I edit the question title to improve it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287832/should-i-edit-the-question-title-to-improve-it), [Titles Matter In Questions: Edit those first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268437/titles-matter-in-questions-edit-those-first), and [Should a post title be modified to fit the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278431/should-a-post-title-be-modified-to-fit-the-problem). However, I do not think the answers directly address my concern.

Today a user posted a question [Case insensitive regex matching both à and À](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164763/case-insensitive-regex-matching-both-%C3%A0-and-%C3%80). So, now in there will be *specific* question to the French character set of accented "A". I flagged the question as a duplicate (and it was so marked) of the question [Java case insensitive regex matching doesn't work with letter Ñ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659282/java-case-insensitive-regex-matching-doesnt-work-with-letter-%C3%91). So there is a *specific* question to the Spanish accented N. 
This previous "N" question directly addressed the problem space (using case insensitive search with unicode characters; the answer is perfectly applicable to the newer question), but it was not going to be found (easily) by someone searching for a French accented A. (Note: searching for "case insensitive regex" doesn't reveal either of these questions on the first page of the Google results, and, if the research is accurate, [91% of searchers do not go past the first page](https://www.quora.com/How-many-Google-searchers-go-to-page-two-of-their-search-results)).

The issue, in my opinion, is that the title of the original question is overly specific. Yes, the user was concerned about the "Ñ" character in the original question, but the question and solution are applicable to any such accented letter. The newer question is overly constrained to à and À characters.

It seems like adjusting the original question's title to be more general (e.g., How does one do a case-insenstive regex matching with accented or unicode characters) (and perhaps appending "e.g., à, À, Ñ") would fit both the solution and the actual problem space.

However, I was taken to task in a completely different question for suggesting a question was duplicate because -- despite the fact the user wanted to format a `Calendar` object -- there was not a direct question on how to format a `GregorianCalendar` object. Now, the latter can be formatted in the same way as a Calendar, but the individual felt that since a search didn't directly reveal formatting a GreogrianCalendar, it wasn't a duplicate of the various Calendar formatting answers. So in this case the individual felt that a bunch of very specific questions (and titles) was better than the more general approach.

So, my question is should earlier questions which have overly specific titles have said titles edited to be more general, thus perhaps broadening the applicability?

In "Titles matter in Questions", the author asserted:

> Titles are the single most important part of the question for a search engine and for the human eye. If the title doesn't accurately reflect the problem, then it should be edited to do so.

I agree with that assertion. But in the case outlined above, it seems to me that a title can accurately reflect the problem the user had from the specific perspective of the user, without accurately revealing the general nature of the problem. In turn, this lack of generality results in additional, essentially duplicated questions (which take time to answer or flag). As an aside, it also seems to me that such issues are more endemic to questions that start with "X doesn't work" or "How do I do X specific thing".

In "Should a post title be modified to fit the problem?", the individual stated:

> Good titles should be concise, specifc [sic] and summarize the problem

The issue I have is that the overly specific titles can actually be detrimental. The accepted answer to this "Should a post title be modified" meta-question asked the rhetorical question of "what good does it do anyone when you have a title that does not accurately describe the problem?" The problem is, I think, that a title can accurately describe the problem from the perspective of the user, but not the perspective of the general case.

I will caveat the foregoing with the fact that I primarily look at Java questions. It is certainly possible that the other tags/communities have less of an issue than I perceive.

In conclusion (violating a rule of asking only a single question):

- Should the user-centric specific title be preferred over a more general title
- Should one consider editing the title of a question (especially when it is the basis of a referenced duplicate) to more accurately reflect the general nature of the question and answers?

Comment: Well, it depends. People are bad at coming up with search terms and good titles, which is likely why there are so many duplicates. If you rename all the duplicates to better more general titles, you're removing possible search terms that would eventually lead to the same canonical post. so... Yeah, in some cases they should be updated, but in others doing so may cause more harm than good.

Comment: You can make a change that doesn't invalidate the answers? Yes. Do it.

Comment: I would wait until you have >2k rep if you're going to do this. Then no one will have to review your changes, and we won't have to deal with all of the "my edit got rejected" questions that result from naïve reviewers.