# Should I edit a question title to add an error message fragment?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits, title

I sometimes see posts with question titles along the lines of "such and such won't work", without an indication of what the error message is.  Often the error message is in the body of the question.  That makes it difficult for knowledgeable people to notice a question they know the answer to, and for other people having the same problem to find that question.

Should I edit the post to add distinguishing elements of that error message to the title?

If so, what is the preferred way of doing so?

#### Example

[Original title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055176/visual-studio-code-wont-open-via-command-line):

> Visual Studio Code won't open via command line

Error message line from question body:

```
Error: watch /home/andre/.config/Code/User ENOSPC
```

[Suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23990007):

> Visual Studio Code won't open via command line: watch ENOSPC

#### Evidence in favor of editing

[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) emphasizes the importance of the title, and says to "Include any error messages".

[How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title), [first answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/600735) says to "Make the topic stand out", which I think is the effect of adding distinguishing error message elements.  The [third answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112966/600735) says the title should be searchable, descriptive, and precise, which is often not the case without anything about the error message.

[Should I edit the question title to improve it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287832/should-i-edit-the-question-title-to-improve-it) says "if you can fix a title to match the question do so", and also "The title is ... part of the indexing on Google".

#### Evidence against editing

[How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title), [first answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/600735) also says to "Use proper grammar and write in question form".  That's sometimes hard to do with error message elements, especially if I want to keep the title concise and also keep to the original author's intent.  (But if this is the central issue, perhaps I just need to get more creative?)

My [recent attempt to edit a title in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23990007) was rejected with the reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Within that list of reasons, the only one that seems like it might apply is "actively harm readability", which in retrospect I can sort of understand since my addition might look like two random appended words (if one does not read my edit summary or the question body), but there is often a risk of that since error messages themselves can be cryptic.

If I were to re-submit this edit suggestion, I think I would suggest the title:

> Visual Studio Code won't open via command line: "Error: watch ... ENOSPC"

If the issue is that I did not change the title to be a question, I might try a more drastic edit, at the risk of changing author intent:

> Why does Visual Studio Code fail to start, printing "Error: watch ... ENOSPC"?

Are either of these sufficiently better to be accepted?

(For completeness: The rejected edit in question also modified the question body.  Although my main concern was the title, I also edited the body because my [other rejected title edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23933349) was rejected in part because it "did not correct critical issues with the post", while the [preferred edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56001492/revisions) made (only) fairly small adjustments to the body (and also in part due to [issues with the new title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332907/is-it-ok-to-edit-the-title-of-a-question-when-the-author-edits-the-body-changin)).  So I tried to fix anything I could see wrong in the body along with the title change.  I'm fairly confident the body edits were not the reason for the rejection, but not 100%.)

Comment: I like "Visual Studio Code won't open via command line: "Error: watch ... ENOSPC". Adding "Why" really does not do much, clearly specifying that "watch ENOSPC" is VS Code's error message and not random text is important especially for reviewers who may not have such deep knowledge of this error... Consider using "VS Code" instead of full name  -  I'm pretty sure people will search for both, but VS Code is much shorter.